# MariaDB - how to stop it complaining about empty values in configuration?

Tags: mariadb

I'm moving a site to another server. Both are running **MariaDB**. The old one is:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.8-MariaDB
```

The new one:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.11-MariaDB
```

On the old server in my.cnf, I put:

```
[mysqld]
...otherlines
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

This allowed me to run the commands I wanted. So I'm trying to do the same on the new server, but it keeps complaining:

```
Field 'shipping_name' doesn't have a default value
```

If I run this command from the script to see what sql_mode its running, I get:

```
SELECT @@SQL_MODE, @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE;
```

[image]

What am I missing? Has something changed from **10.5.8-MariaDB** to **10.6.11-MariaDB** around this?

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE TABLE` for that table.

Comment: @RickJames thanks. I looked at the structure, and it didn't have `DEFAULT NULL` set on those fields. So I did that, but really I don't want to have to go through all my DB structures on all the sites I'm going to be pulling over, just to make sure they have that set. Is there no way to just tell it to ignore those errors?